# How to change label's text font in tcltk

Tags: button, fonts, label, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a GUI with a label and a button. When I press the button a new window comes up were from  I have to choose the font. This part I managed to do it.

It is on tcltk help site a code witch helped me to make font window appear. There are shown 4 procedures. The first and second proc I used for the font window appearance. The link is: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/fontchooser.htm

My  question is: how can I link the font that I choose with the label's text?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: The font dialog is rather tricky to use because it is not consistently modal or non-modal on different platforms. _Use the recipe on that manual page_ to save yourself a lot of trouble, though you're free to adapt it once it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

The label widget, like the text widget, has a `-font` option. All you've got to do is to make things set themselves up. The way in this case would be to add the following binding (assuming you've got the procedures and have made a label, geometry-managed it, and stored its name in the `thelabel` variable):

```
bind $thelabel <1> {focus %W; fontchooserFocus %W}
```

Labels don't normally take focus, and don't have any default key bindings, but they *can* be forced to have the focus and that's useful to indicate what is being configured. (This is particularly important on OSX, where the font dialog is very different in how it works to on other platforms).

Comment: Well it doesn't work. But I don't think that I placed that code line properly. Where should I place it?

Comment: You've not showed us _exactly_ what you've tried so guessing is a touch tricky.

Comment: Looking at the code you've posted, you don't appear to have put the line @DonalFellows suggested in at all. In your place, I'd try putting it directlay after you create the label with `label $bind.label#1...`. No guarantees. Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work how you recommended @murdglaw, or maybe it's something I'm doing wrong. After I put that code line the GUI becomes empty, with no element on it. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Are you sure that the code line is correctly written ?